# Include all W-2 forms on a Part-Year-Resident State return?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

I lived in State1 for the first 10 months of 2012, and then State2 for the remainder of the year.  I've already e-filed my federal return and my state return for State1.  However, my tax software wouldn't let me e-file my state return for State2, so I'm filing it via mail.

I'm sending my W-2 form from my job in State2.  Do I also need to include my W-2 form from my other job in State1?

Comment: What do the state's tax form instruction say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the advice of @user102008 , I read-through the booklet of State2, and it said the following:

```
Also, enclose:
• All W-2s and 1099s on which [State2] and/or county tax withholding amounts appear
• Any 1099G showing unemployment compensation, and
• A check/money order, if applicable.
```

... so I'm not going to include my State1 W-2s.